# What is the difference between "You have been banned from this server" and "You were banned from this server"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

What is the difference between the following sentences?

> 1 You have been banned from this server.
>
> 2 You were banned from this server.

Comment: There are may questions here on the difference between present perfect and past tense.  can you find any more that are duplicates of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is a notification you will receive shortly after you have been banned. It is recent and news, so to speak. There is a connection to the present.

The second sentence means the same, but you "were" banned puts the banning in the past, even if the past is recent. It is not news anymore. There is no connection to the present.